# Hashing Python closure ignores __closure__ variables

Tags: python, closures

I'm using Python 2.7 and notice that it seems to ignore closure variables when computing hash().  Is this the intended behavior?  It seems strange since == works as I would expect.

```
def foo(x):
    def bar():
        print x
    return bar

>>> foo(1)
<function bar at 0x2aaaaba0e758>
>>> foo(2)
<function bar at 0x2aaaaba0e848>
>>> foo(1) == foo(2)
False
>>> hash(foo(1))
-9223369104822759804
>>> hash(foo(2))
-9223369104822759804
>>> foo(1).__closure__
(<cell at 0x2aaaaba08130: int object at 0x7a97d8>,)
>>> foo(2).__closure__
(<cell at 0x2aaaaba08168: int object at 0x7a97c0>,)
>>>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 2.7? I ask because you're using `__closure__` (version 3.x) while it would be called `func_closure` in 2.7.

Comment: You are discarding the generated `bar` function. This makes Python garbage collect it and reuse the id (which is used for hash). Try saving the `bar` function and then comparing them.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to explain things.  I also notice foo(1) != foo(1), so equality and hashing both seem to work in a somewhat counter intuitive way.  It's too bad since I was hoping to memoize a function that was taking a closure as a parameter but that won't work with this implementation.